# How to get mask of rows for a time range in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` `DataFrame` with date column named `SDate`, I would like to find the rows for which `SDate`'s hour is between 2 and 4 pm, something like :

```
d=pd.read_csv("data.csv",parse_dates=['SDate'])
indices=np.nonzero(d.SDate.hour>=2&d.SDate.hour<=4)[0]
```

but this doesnt work like that. how to do it in the most pandas and pythonic way?

Comment: Can you also provide some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a mask, this should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/2/2018', freq='H'), columns=['SDate'])
mask = (df.SDate.dt.hour >= 2) & (df.SDate.dt.hour <= 4)
print(mask.values)
```

**Output**

```
[False False  True  True  True False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False]
```

In the above example df is DataFrame with a [datetime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html) dtype column `SDate`, [dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html) is an accessor object for datetimelike properties, like hour.

Comment: right, can you further explain what is SDate.dt, like what type is it and what does it do

Answer (score 1):

You can use [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) too

```
d = d.set_index('SDate')
d.between_time(start_time = '14:00', end_time = '16:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your conditions via parentheses:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01 02:00', '2015-12-25 15:00'])

indices = np.nonzero(s.hour>=2 & s.hour<=4)[0]
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Int64Index'

indices = np.nonzero((s.hour>=2) & (s.hour<=4))[0]
# array([0], dtype=int64)
```

Note you can use [`pd.Series.argmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.Series.argmax.html) for this calculation, as a scalar output is sufficient:

```
indices = ((s.hour>=2) & (s.hour<=4)).argmax()
# 0
```